# Eye strain using 3D screens

Tags: eyes, perception, human-eye

I don't know if this is a physics or a biology question but this might be better orientated around the element of how the human eye works in a 3D visual situation than physics.

Given the rise of 3D virtual reality headsets such as the Oculus Rift. I have a question about eye strain relating to these.

Often on a computer, eye strain comes from staring at the monitor for too long of which is the same continuous distance that your eyes have to focus on... thus causing computer vision syndrome (as well as lack of blinking). Meaning you should look at an object far away every X amount of minutes to rest the eyes.

How ever in a virtual headset, although the monitor is much closer, it is in 3D (or a fake 3D). So i wondered, does the eye muscles adjust based on this trick of fake 3D. Or will your eyes still focus on the fixed distance to the screen display regardless of the fake 3D perception, meaning you still get eye strain either way?

If you imagine looking through a 3D VR Headset, staring at a 3D object in the distance, is that going to create the same change in muscle adjustment in the eye as looking at a physical object in the real world of the same distance.

Essentially - 3D VR headsets could reduce the amount of eye strain. Because the eye is busy adjusting all the time for these "fake" distance illusions, rather than forced to focus in one way for a long length of time such as a 2D monitor. It might help people who struggle with computer vision syndrome perhaps?

Has any studies been done on this?

Comment: I think all illusions are based on certain drawbacks of our own eyes.

Comment: Most likely but thats a rather different topic entirely :P